# How to prevent duplicate entries in concurrent requests while using Sequelize in Node.js-Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working with a Node.js Express server and encountering an issue related to duplicate entries in a MySQL database using Sequelize.

In the code snippet below, I check if there is an entry exists for an incoming email id, and new entry is made with relevant logs if the entry check request gives a null value. However, I'm facing a problem where the "else" conditions are being evaluated as true twice, resulting in a duplicate entry SQL error.

```
async function creditCheck(req, res) { 

try { 
let userEntry; 

const { user_email } = req.body;

const user = await userData.findOne({ where: { email: user_email }, raw: true });  

if (user) {

    userEntry = {
      email: user_email,
      creditBalance: user.credit_balance,
    }

    console.log(`Registered user: ${user_email} -> credit Check `);
    responseData.msg = 'credit check success';
    responseData.body = userEntry;
    return res.status(200).send(responseData);

  } else {
    console.log(`unregistered user ${user_email} -> credit Check `);

    await userData.create({
      email: user_email,
      creditBalance: 0,
    });

    userEntry = {
      email: user_email,
      creditBalance: 0,
    }
    
    responseData.body = userEntry;
    return res.status(200).send(responseData);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('credit check error: ', error);
  responseData.msg = 'credit check error';
  return res.status(500).send(responseData);
}};
```

LOG:

```
unregistered user xxx@ymail.com -> credit check
unregistered user: xxx@ymail.com -> credit check
*** Sequalize error: duplicate entry ***
```

I double-checked the request count.

There is only one request is sent at a time from the frontend

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You write "both `else` conditions", but your code contains only one `else`.

Comment: How did you check if the request is being sent once from the FE?